# CSS grid framework that uses CSS grid

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid, css-frameworks

I'm trying to find a framework that support the CSS grid system. So far, googling the subject only gives me frameworks based on floats and Flexbox. It might be the word "css grid" which makes it hard for Google to really find what I'm looking for.

Anyone found a good framework that they can recommend?

Comment: You could lookout for bootstrap. What do you think?

Comment: @Anmol I'm not that familiar with Bootstrap 4 yet, but I think that Bootstrap 3 does not use the css Grid System. It uses an own implementation of a grid System.

Comment: I'm trying to get away from Bootstrap, as I don't need all the other stuff it comes with, just the grid :)

Comment: I don't know of one - but you could make your own. If you are familiar with Bootstrap this might help the transition https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/04/replace-bootstrap-layouts-with-css-grid/

Comment: I thought that a big part of the CSS Grid concept was to avoid frameworks. LOL.

Comment: May I ask why you are not willing to just use the CSS grid?

Comment: I am working on creating a small understandable framework for css grid. Made in sass.

Comment: There's no reason this post should be being downvoted, it's a valid question. Grid is not sufficient on it's own without the components and styling that Bootstrap offers. Sure, you can write your own components or use individual jQuery libraries to compensate, but it's not as elegant and consistent as using a single framework. For now I'm sticking with Bootstrap simply for this reason.

Answer (score 6):

CSS grid does not need a framework, if you understand it very well it work as a standalone layout method rather to add or make part if a css framework.

Comment: I disagree. Grid is not sufficient on it's own without the components and styling that Bootstrap offers. Sure, you can write your own components or use individual jQuery libraries to compensate, but it's not as elegant and consistent as using a single framework. For now I'm sticking with Bootstrap simply for this reason. Hopefully in the future Bootstrap switches to CSS3 grid, or some other Bootstrap style frameworks are released that use grid.